# JDBC get database unique id for a record

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to know if there is any way of getting a database's identifier for a record through JDBC.

For example, i am querying the database and getting back a `ResultSet` which i store in a `Map`. I give an Id to each record based on the order that i retrieve them from the ResultSet.

Now i would like to re-query the Database and be able to correlate the new `ResultSet` to my already existing records. So, if a record got deleted, ideally, i would be able to just remove it from the `Map` by using the unique identifier.

My problem here is that i cannot find a unique identifier coming from the RDBMS itself. I tried using the `ResultSet.getRowId()` but this method is not implemented by all JDBC driver providers.

Could anyone thing of any way to get a get an identifier from the ResultSet that uniqely identifies a record in the Database ?

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck so far? And just for curiosity, why are you implementing this and what do you need to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, every Record in your database should have an identifier (Primary Key). The best approach is always try to stick to this.

> So, if a record got deleted, ideally, i would be able to just remove it from the Map by using the unique identifier.

Maybe clearing the Map and mapping it again would be an option.

Comment: Hello Everton. Thanks for your answers. I already implemented a solutions based on the <code>Connection.getDatabaseMetaData</code> and retrieving the Primary key from there. My problem with this is that the solution should be generic and not assume that every table has a PrimaryKey. I know that every table <b>should</b> have a PrimaryKey to identify it, but unfortunately cannot rely on that. I was thinking if am able to get a RowId that the RDBMS itself is using for every record. This way i could retrieve the Id every time i iterate through the result set and use it accordignly.

Comment: You are hard pressed to implement a generic solution for that. If you are developing a Framework/API, maybe you should ignore tables that doesn't have those identifiers. I can't se a good option here.

Comment: And generically speaking, there is no such thing as a unique identifier for each row in RDBMS, apart from primary keys.

Comment: Yes indeed, you are absolutely right. It is a pain dealing with such a thing. I think i would have to make some compromise here to make it work in a generic way. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Would a ROWCOUNT serve your purpose? Or maybe a composition of the Records values, like mapping the record to a java bean and then take the `.hashCode()`.

Comment: At the moment i am using the naive ROWCOUNT approach. But doing this has flaws, as noone guarantees me that every time i execute the same query the ResultSet will return me the rows in the same order. Additionally, this approach would be good if i was not expecting record deletions, but only record insert. It would be easy to identify when a record is added, but it would almost be impossible to identify in a performant way that a record was deleted, as its ROWCOUNT_ID would be replaced.

Comment: On the other hand the approach with the <pre>hashCode()</pre> is definetely a good way to go, but it means that i would have to store 2 instances of the same record in memory, in order to compare them. I think i will try the PRIMARY_KEY approach and take some safety measures for tables without a PK.

Comment: If you need to go back to the tables based on that identifier, then you are screwed. Even if you take the `hashcode`, in case you don't have PK's, you can have duplicated records.

Comment: Edited with an advise for the deletion case

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the primary key to identify the record?

Comment: Hello Smitesh. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, as i explained to Everton's answer, i cannot use the PrimaryKey, as the solution should work for any table (not know beforehand), thus i cannot assume that every table would have a primary key.